# How to make Xcode execution to skip or jump statement when pause is pressed to resume

Tags: iphone

I don't know how to code this but i want program to skip or jump this statement from executing

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
```

when pause is pressed to resume play.

Reason i want this cause in play/pause button everything is good except when pause is pressed to resume it starts reloading view controllers by executing this statement from the below code

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
```

I have tried so many different ways to solve this issues but nothing is working out.

```
 if([audioPlayer isPlaying]){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
}else {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
```

That's how loading view controllers one after other

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
 {  
  First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
  firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
  CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
  [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
  [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
  [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction       functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
  [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
  [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
  [firstController release];
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  
  }

  -(void)Second 
  {
   Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
   secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
   CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
   [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
   [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
   [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
   [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
   [self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 
   [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
   [secondController release];
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
```

This is my last attempt to see if i can find some solution for this issue. I have spent two weeks on this issue but no success.

If someone can solve my this issue.

Thanks so much for help.

Comment: can you explain the code written inside of your play/pause methods ?

Comment: when you need to call this method "displayviewsAction" ? On first play or pause ?

Comment: When play button is pressed the very first time it starts NSTimer, starts playing an audio file and based on NSTimer, view controllers will load one after the other. When pause button is pressed again to resume it resumes everything from that point audio file, NSTimer and view controllers from the same point where it was paused which is good. However, at the same time it starts loading the view controllers again one after the other from the beginning based on NSTimer which is not good. on the first play calling this displayviewsaction method to loadviewcontrollers one after the other.

Comment: can you explain the codes written inside of the displayviewsaction  method ? Did you used a boolean for this ?

Comment: updated my post please check it

Comment: Please check the answer, and please tell me if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one little bit complex solution.
In you `.h` file create a `BOOL isFirstTime; int methodSelector;`.
In your implementation file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 isFirstTime = YES;
 methodSelector = 1;
}
```

and change your code like this:

```
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
switch(methodSelector)
{
 case 1:self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
 break;
 case 2:self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 break;
 .
 .
 .


 }
}
if(isFirstTime == YES)
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
isFirstTime  = NO;
}
```

set the `methodSelector` in your view changing methods accordingly. In `Second` method set it as 2 in `Third` set it as 3 and so on.

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
 {  
  First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
  firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
  CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
  [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
  [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
  [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction       functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
  [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
  [self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
  [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
  [firstController release];
methodSelector = 2;
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];  
  }

  -(void)Second 
  {
   Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
   secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
   CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
   [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
   [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
   [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
   [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
   [self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 
   [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
   [secondController release];
methodSelector = 3;
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
```

`methodSelector` is used for calling the method after pausing.

Comment: @user1452248: I have changed the case 1 statement. Please check that.

Comment: yeah same issue i tried it is reloading view controller when you press pause again to resume and plus this time it start loading immediately after i hit play it should start loading after 11 seconds as per nstimer scheduled for firstviewcontroller

Comment: @user1452248: it is pretty simple. Change the case statements to  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } like that. And one more thing I noticed. Set methodSelector = 2; in displayviewsAction. methodSelector = 3; in Second method. Now it will work

Comment: I m not getting this part Set methodSelector = 2; in displayviewsAction. methodSelector = 3; in Second method.

Comment: ok, i'll explain. Suppose if you are pausing the player when the displayviewsAction: method is executing. The value of methodSelector is 1, right ? Then you resume the play, the switch condition will again call displayviewsAction, because methodSelector is 1. So set the value ofmethodSelector to 2 in displayviewsAction method. And set it to 3 in Second method.

Comment: i tried but it is still reloading view controllers again from the beginning when i hit pause again to playback

Comment: i removed method selector and then it is working fine not reloading view controllers again from the beginning one after the other. Thanks so much for all your time and help. Appreciate so much.

Comment: it is working fine after i removed method selector because there is no need for method selector displayviewsaction will load automatically view controllers one after the other based on timer and i kept isfirsttime which is avoiding to reload view controllers after pause is pressed again to resume.

Comment: @user1452248: it's ok. Your issue is resolved, that makes me happy.

Comment: Now app crashes after i stop and play it again gives error [__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceNow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b4dc0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12714/discussion-between-midhun-mp-and-user1452248) please click on this link